# Gnuplot: line 0: no previous plot

Tags: python, bash, sed, gnuplot, rtl-sdr

I am trying to save the Gnuplot plot in PNG that I get with my SDR and a tool named `rtl_power_fftw`.

This command displays my plot on the screen but I want to save it in PNG:

```
rtl_power_fftw -f 900M:950M -n 10 -b 512 -q |
sed -u '/rtl-power-fftw/s/.*/ plot "-"/;/^$/{N;s/^\n$/e/}' |
gnuplot -p
```

So after a few researches, I tried this:

```
rtl_power_fftw -f 900M:950M -n 10 -b 512 -q |
sed -u '/rtl-power-fftw/s/.*/ plot "-"/;/^$/{N;s/^\n$/e/}' |
gnuplot -p -e "set term png; set output 'output.png'; replot; set term x11; set output"`
```

But this command gives me the following error: **line 0: no previous plot** when I use the command **replot**.

I would be very thankful if you can help me to save this plot in PNG, no matter the solution: command line, bash script or a mix of the two.

Comment: Then don't use `replot`?

Comment: Okay, I don't have the error anymore but I cannot open the PNG file (it has no data)

Comment: That makes sense. The commands in `-e` don't tell Gnuplot what to plot.

Comment: When I add parameters to gnuplot I feel like it doesn't recognize anymore my previous plot that comes from rtl_power_fftw + sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `rtl_power_fftw -f 900M:950M -n 10 -b 512 -q` apparently contains some GnuPlot commands, but we can't know what they are. You want to modify the `sed` script to add the `set term` and `set output` commands at the beginning of the generated script.

```
rtl_power_fftw -f 900M:950M -n 10 -b 512 -q |
sed -u -e "1i\\ set term png; set output 'output.png'" \
    -e '/rtl-power-fftw/s/.*/ plot "-"/;/^$/{N;s/^\n$/e/}' |
gnuplot -p
```

What exactly works depends on your `sed` dialect. Perhaps on MacOS try

```
rtl_power_fftw -f 900M:950M -n 10 -b 512 -q |
sed -u -e "1i\\
set term png; set output 'output.png'
" \
    -e '/rtl-power-fftw/s/.*/ plot "-"/;/^$/{N;s/^\n$/e/}' |
gnuplot -p
```

(The `-u` option is probably quite unnecessary here, too.)